Geodesics in metric spaces
When I'm walking my dogs, what portion of my time is spent travelling along a geodesic to get home? OK, I'm not really asking that question, but it made me think of the following: if I travel a closed path in a metric space, what can I say about the proportion of the path that is in the same direction as the geodesic?
So one obvious possibility is "none": if I walk in a circle in the Euclidean plane, my direction of motion (tangent to the circle) never coincides with the geodesic (secant between current location and the origin).
But to take an example closer to my actual walk: let my set of points be the grid $\{(x,y):x,y \in \mathbb{R}, x \in \mathbb{Z} \, {\rm and/or}\, y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, and my distance is just the shortest walk along the grid (this can be made formal with a modification to the taxicab metric, but the intuition is more important). In this case, any closed loop must at some point approach its terminus along a geodesic.
Is this a studied property of metric spaces? It seems related to dimension somehow, but I'm far enough past my topology classes to not really remember any of that. Any tips on where I might look for more information would be appreciated!

The meaning of "at some point approach its terminus along a geodesic" is unclear. What one can prove is that there is a nondegenerate interval whose image under the map defining your loop is contained in a geodesic. Is it what you are trying to say?

@MoisheKohan Yes, that is certainly a more precise way to say what I was getting at.

I do not think this particular question is discussed anywhere. But, first, let's state cleanly what you are trying to say.
Definition. Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A geodesic in $(X,d)$ is a map $c: I\to X$ from an interval $I\subset \mathbb R$ to $X$ such that
$$
d(c(s), c(t))=|s-t|
$$
for all $s, t\in I$. One frequently conflates geodesics and their images in $X$. A metric space $(X, d)$ is said to be a geodesic metric space if any two points in $X$ can be connected by a geodesic. More precisely, for any pair of points $x, y\in X$ there exists a geodesic $c: [a,b]\to X$ such that $c(a)=x, c(b)=y$.
Now, let's state your question:
What are conditions on geodesic metric spaces $(X,d)$ such that the following is true for all nonconstant loops $p: S^1\to X$ in $(X,d)$:
There exists a nondegenerate subarc $\alpha\subset S^1$ such that $p(\alpha)$ is contained in the image of a geodesic in $(X,d)$?
Your idea is that if $(X,d)$ is (in some sense) 1-dimensional, then this property holds. You also observed correctly (although did  not really prove) that this property holds for metric graphs such as the standard grid in the plane.
Example. There exists a compact geodesic metric space $(X,d)$ of Hausdorff dimension 1 such that the above property fails.
Start with the standard unit circle $C$ in the plane. I will enlarge $C$ to a metric space $(X,d)$ as follows. For every $n\in \mathbb N$ and $k=1,..., n$, connect all pairs of points $e^{(k-1)(2\pi i/n)}, e^{k(2\pi i/n)}$ by the Euclidean line segment $s_{n,k}$. Let $X$ be the union of $C$ and all line segments $s_{n,k}$ as above, $X=C \cup S$. This is clearly a compact subset of the plane (with the subspace topology). I will define a metric $d$ on $X$ as follows. For each segment $s_{n,k}$ I will use the restriction of the Euclidean metric to this segment. (i) Suppose that a path $p: [a,b]\to X$ is a subsegment of one of the geodesic segments $s_{n,k}$. Then the length $L(p)$ of $p$ is defined to be its Euclidean length.  (ii) Suppose next that $[a,b)$ admits a countably infinite subdivision by points
$$
t_0=a< t_1< t_2<....
$$
such that the restriction of a path $p: [a,b]\to X$ to each $[t_j, t_{j+1}]$ is a path in one of the segments $s_{n,k}$. Then
$$
L(p)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty L(p|_{[t_j, t_{j+1}]}). 
$$
(iii) Lastly, if $p$ is a concatenation $p_1\star ... \star p_m$ of one of the paths as in (ii), then
$$
L(p)=\sum_{j=1}^m L(p_j). 
$$
I will call a path $p$ in $X$ admissible if it is a concatenation as in (iii).
I leave it to you to verify that any two points in $X$ can be connected by an admissible path $p$ of finite length $L(p)$. Define $d: X\times X\to [0,\infty)$ as
$$
d(x,y)=\inf_{p} L(p)
$$
where the infimum is taken over all admissible paths $p$ as above connecting $x$ to $y$. You will verify that $d$ defines a metric on $X$ and the topology induced by this metric is equivalent to the subspace topology on $X$ induced from the plane. The construction I described is very common in geometry, it is called "metric defined by a length structure." See for instance,
Burago, D.; Burago, Yu.; Ivanov, S., A course in metric geometry, Graduate Studies in Mathematics. 33. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). xiv, 415 p. (2001). ZBL0981.51016.
By compactness of $X$, Arzla-Ascoli theorem implies that $(X,d)$ is a geodesic metric space. The subset $S\subset X$ is a countable union of geodesic segments in $(X,d)$. In particular, $S$ has Hausdorff dimension 1. It is a computation (not a very hard one) to check that $C$ (with the restriction of the metric $d$) also has Hausdorff dimension 1 (the metric $d$ on $X$ is Lipschitz-equivalent to the restriction of the Euclidean metric). Thus, $(X,d)$ has Hausdorff dimension 1 as well.
Now, consider a simple loop $p: S^1\to X$ which is the inclusion map $C\to X$. By the construction of the metric $d$, there is no nondegenerate subarc $\alpha$ in $C$ which is a geodesic in $(X,d)$ (since $\alpha$ contains pairs of points of the form $e^{(k-1)(2\pi i/n)}, e^{k(2\pi i/n)}$).
